# Anybody using Expression web to remote edit php files on a *nix server?

Tags: expression-web

I am trying to see if anybody is aware of any ssh or ftp ways of editing files in expression web. This is similar to notepad++. I am already aware of sftpdrive option. I am looking for something that is free, and robust.

I have not played with open site feature in Expression Web. I am not sure if this will work well with a php site on a Linux box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect your Expression Web directly to any FTP server in the open site dialog by typing the ftp address in the site name placeholder like ftp://myftpsite.com. Expression web ask you for your login and password and list your folders to begin to edit your files. It’s very easy, no problems at all.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use samba or nfs to mount a directory on your local machine. If the server is live, you should restriction connections by ip and/or with a vpn.

Be aware that some editors will lag quite a lot with these solutions though, especially with large files.